# Cloudant replication skips some documents

Tags: couchdb, database-replication, cloudant

I am in the process of moving our data from one Cloudant instance to another one. As a good way to move data I created replication documents for continuous replication. Most of them replicate all documents (as expected as I did not use any filters) but some skip several documents.

The 2 databases with problems both store only new documents (no updates, no deletions). After investigation of the larger db (>30 Mio docs) I noticed that only documents created after a specific date are skipped. Most days since this date miss about 1/3 of the created documents. 
Occasionally I noticed errors in the replication document which usually disappear again quickly and the status switches back to 'Triggered'.

The `worker_died` error message is reported as `{[{<<"error">>,<<"too_large">>}, {<<"reason">>,<<"the request entity is too large">>}]}`.
The source database has no indication of problems.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are replicating from an older, either dedicated or metered Cloudant account to a newer instance on IBM Bluemix Public. On the older instances, the max request size is 64M, whereas on the newer instances this limit is reduced to 1M. This discrepancy is likely the problem.

During replication, documents are batched when written to the source. Provided that your documents themselves are smaller than 1M you should be able to adjust the batch size to squeeze under the 1M request limit size. The batch size is defaulted to 500, but this can be changed using the `worker_batch_size` parameter; see

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/advanced_replication.html#performance-related-options

If some of your documents are larger that 1M, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't realize that a dedicated Cloudant instance would use a different batch size. I stared another replication with `worker_batch_size=1`. It will probably run for several days but if the result is correct I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, xpqz, you were leading me in the right direction.
Reducing the worker_batch_size alone did not solve the problems as we have some documents larger than 1MB.
After adding another filter to skip all documents larger than 1MB all smaller docs were replicated.
Unfortunately Cloudant does not skip larger documents and moves on but it retries to replicate the same large document over and over again so all documents afterwards will never be replicated.

- create dd with a size filter:

  "filters": {"doc_size": "function(doc, req){\r\n    if (JSON.stringify(doc).length > 1048575 ) {\r\n        return false;\r\n    }\r\n    return true; \r\n}"}
- add filter to the replication doc:

  "filter": "/doc_size",

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer so it can help others. Thanks!